# Count from json data Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm looking to count from some json data but it's outputting:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

View

```
<%= @overall %>
```

Where the 1's are greater than 40. instead of '2'.

json data is formatted as from a url:

```
{"status": "ok", "data": [{"2014-06-16": 32.1},{"2014-06-17": 30.2},{"2014-06-18": 42.9}]} etc
```

**Controller**

```
@data = JSON.parse(open(@temperature.url).read)
@overall = []

    @data['data'].each do |data|
      dates << data.keys
      temps << data.values
      @overall << data.values.count { |i| i > 40 }
    end
```

Comment: Not understanding your question. What's this thing look like you're trying to count from?

Comment: Hi @MohamedElMahallawy the data from which i'm trying to count from is the json data from a url.

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of temperatures that are over 40?

Comment: Thats correct @TarynEast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since JSON data: is an array I am assuming that multiple dates are represented by multiple hashes (one for each day).  Is this correct?

```
{"status": "ok", "data": [{"2014-06-16": 42.1}, {"2014-06-17": 45.5}]
```

If that's the case, this should work:

```
@data = JSON.parse(open(@temperature.url).read)
dates = @data['data'].map {|data| data.keys.first}
temps = @data['data'].map {|data| data.values.first}
@overall = temps.count {|temp| temp > 40}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok - this wil solve the issue

```
@data = JSON.parse(open(@temperature.url).read)
@overall = []

@data['data'].each do |data|
  dates << data.keys
  temps << data.values
end


forty_count = temps.flatten.count {|i| i > 40 }
```

the problem with your above code is that you can't do a count on-the-fly... you can only count when you have the full set of temperatures - which only happens when you get to the end.

also the way you are adding the "data.values" to the `temps` array, makes it into an array of arrays, which you can see if you do  it this way:

```
data = [{"2014-06-16" => 32.1},{"2014-06-17" => 30.2},{"2014-06-18" => 42.9}] 
data.each do |data|
  temps << data.values 
end 
puts temps.inspect  #  [[32.1], [30.2], [42.9]]
puts temps.flatten.inspect  #  [32.1, 30.2, 42.9]

temps.count {|i| i > 40 }         # explodes!
temps.flatten.count {|i| i > 40 } # 1
```

Comment: Thanks Taryn. Same issue though except replaces '1' with 'true'.

Comment: Another great solution. Voted.